# Trouble reading MODBUS register using Python

Tags: python, pyserial, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am trying to use Python (PyCharm) to read a register on a modbus device. I have confirmed the COM port, Baud rate and other communication settings and I can use the devices application to read the value (it is a water level logger). I am getting no response from the instrument.

Register is readable in mbpoll using -

```
mbpoll -B -m RTU  -t 4:float -a 1 -b 19200 -r 46 -c 2 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

[image]
(Address different as running on Pi not PC)

And MBPOLL -
[image]
[image]
[image]

My code is as follows -

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)
instrument.serial.port = 'COM5'                     # this is the serial port name
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200         # Baud
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 3          # seconds
instrument.address = 1                         # this is the slave address number
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU   # rtu or ascii mode
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True

temperature = instrument.read_float(registeraddress=40046, functioncode=3, number_of_registers=2, byteorder=0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals
print(temperature)
```

Error Received -
[image]

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)
instrument.serial.port = 'COM5'                     # this is the serial port name
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200         # Baud
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 0.1        # seconds
instrument.address = 1                         # this is the slave address number
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU   # rtu or ascii mode
#nstrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True

temperature = instrument.read_float(registeraddress=45, functioncode=4, number_of_registers=2, byteorder=0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals

try:
    print(temperature)
except:
    print(temperature)
```

Edit to include a try - except

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:
Link to device manual - https://in-situ.com/en/pub/media/support/documents/Modbus_Manual.pdf
Device is a Level Troll 400 Connected to PC via manufactures cable

EDIT 2:
I have tried to incorporate minimal modbus structure but to no avail.

EDIT 3:
I am able to read a register using Modbus Poll. Register is 40046, so I understand this to be register 45 of the holding registers? How do I translate this to minimalmodbus?

EDIT 4:
I am not married to minimal modbus - I am happy to use any tool to get this done

EDIT 5:
I have also tried `depth = instrument.read_long(x, x)` with different values

Comment: Please provide a link to the device manual.

Comment: Done, thank you! FYI - https://in-situ.com/en/pub/media/support/documents/Modbus_Manual.pdf

Comment: `19600` is an unusual baud rate; did you mean `9600` or `19200`? (looks like `19200` is the default).

Comment: 19600 may have been a typo on my part but I have tried a variety of baud rates in my testing including 9600 and I believe 19200. I will retry to confirm this isn’t the cause however. Thanks!

Comment: You will also need to set the serial parameters using the [minimial modbus structure](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#default-values); e.g. `instrument.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN`.

Comment: What is the slave address? 2 or 1? `minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 2) # portname, slaveaddr` vs. `instrument.address = 1`

Comment: In these situations, physical inspection of data on the wire using a logic analyzer greatly simplifies the debugging process. Without one, you're blind.

Comment: Slave is at address 1. As per edits I have connected and read register via Modbus Poll, if that helps?

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it timeout or some other error?

Comment: Please provide full information re the working Mod Poll configuration (ideally in text but a screenshot is better than nothing) and full details of the results (both in ModPoll and from your application).

Comment: Hopefully all requested edits made!

Comment: Maybe `Instrument(...., debug=True)` will print something usefull.

Comment: Exception are caused by `read_float`, not by `print`. And you need `functioncode=3` because the manual doesn't mention a distinction between holding and input registers. Most devices just use holding registers. Personally, I would use input registers for read-only data when I design my own Modbus slaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just updating with the solution if anyone happens to stumble upon this and has the same problem. As semi-alluded to in other suggestions the device I am connecting to has a 'sleep' period or the like and needs to be polled once, unsuccessfully, before successfully returning values for any subsequent polls. I apologies for my armature code but the solution that works for me is the below -

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)
instrument.serial.port = 'COM5'                     # this is the serial port name
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200         # Baud
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 1        # seconds
instrument.address = 1                         # this is the slave address number
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU   # rtu or ascii mode
#nstrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
try:
    temperature = instrument.read_long(registeraddress=9001, functioncode=3,
                                        byteorder=0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals

    print(temperature)


except:
    pass

try:
    temperature = instrument.read_long(registeraddress=9001, functioncode=3,
                                        byteorder=0)  # Registernumber, number of decimals

    print(temperature)


except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

The device manual isn't clear about the register start address, but the first register it mentions has the address of **1**.

Similarly, the *mbpoll* command-line utility (not the one with GUI) isn't very clear about the start address. But its documentation mentions that the default value for `-r` parameter is **1**.

I think it's safe to assume that both use the same addressing which starts from **1**, as the command-line tool has no problems accessing the value.

But *MinimalModbus* API clearly mentions that its register start address is **0**. So when using this library, you need to use `registeraddress = 45` for accessing the temperature, not 46 or 40046.

But why won't **46** work? Normally, one would expect it to grab data starting from the next register and print some garbage, but not timeout. But we can't know how the device works internally. Maybe a request to access the temperature register actually triggers some measurement function and then returns a value. A request to access an unaligned data (with a wrong register value) can be simply rejected by the firmware.

If you still get timeouts with `registeraddress = 45`, your Python runtime may have some problems accessing the serial port. As I stated in my comment, I recommend using a logic analyzer to see what's going on on the wire. Without such a tool, you're doing blind-debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately ```registeraddress = 45``` did not work. I am still in the process of trying to locate a logic analyzer. Just a thought - with MBPOLL it seems the first request times out each time and then only work on subsequent requests (see first line of above screenshot). Is there a way for me to tell python to keep trying until it does manage to get a value rather than end after the first failure? Really appreciate all the efforts here!

Comment: You may try reducing the timeout (0.1 seconds maybe), surrounding the read call with a *try - except* block for catching & ignoring `NoResponseError` in a loop. I have once designed a device which wakes up and responds Modbus quarries once in a second. But the manual of your device doesn't mention any sleep & wakeup mechanism.

Comment: It might be time for me to start looking at other solutions whilst I get to the bottom of this. As a MODBUS expert would you have any advice on where I can start? I need to log data from these devices using a raspberry pi with the long term goal of being able to display it live

Comment: Well, I don't consider myself as a Modbus expert, but I have some experince debugging communications, including USB FS. Again, the first thing you need to do is obtaining a logic analyzer. Even the cheapest ones will do. It saved me from countless hours (probably even days) of debugging time.